# Trying to filter out certain objects/values that are not open

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build this function where I need to filter out certain properties that are not opened (if they are set to false is my current thought process)

I already have the array mapped out with open, prices(it would take to open), and opened (as an array of objects)

My main goal is to filter out the boxes objects that are not opened (so my thinking is trying to filter out those are NOT yet opened).

Example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
let results = code.getOpenedBoxes(data);
      expect(results).to.have.lengthOf(1);

      data.boxes[2].unlocked = true;
      results = code.getOpenedBoxes(data);
      expect(results).to.have.lengthOf(2);
```

Example data:

```
data = {
        counter: 0,
        boxes: [
          { open: 'box_A', price: 50, opened: true },
          { open: 'box_B', price: 200, opened: false },
          { open: 'box_C', price: 500, opened: false }
        ]
      };
    });
```

This is the code that I have so far.

```
function getOpenedBoxes(data) {
  return data.boxes.map((open, price, opened) => {
    return { open, price, opened }
  }).filter(boxes => boxes.opened === false);
}
```

When the code is being returned with this filter, it's returning an array of 3, when I only need it to the ones that are false (unless my logic is off)

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: I try to run your code and I got 0 result. When I remove the `map` function, it returns correctly, which is 2 items in the array.

Answer (score 0):

No need to map the array, you can just filter the `boxes` array:

```js
const data = {
  counter: 0,
  boxes: [
    { open: 'box_A', price: 50, opened: true },
    { open: 'box_B', price: 200, opened: false },
    { open: 'box_C', price: 500, opened: false }
  ]
};

    
const opened = data.boxes.filter(box => box.opened)
console.log('Opened: ', opened)

const notOpened = data.boxes.filter(box => !box.opened)
console.log('Not Opened: ', notOpened)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your mapping is incorrect:

```js
data = {
        counter: 0,
        boxes: [
          { open: 'box_A', price: 50, opened: true },
          { open: 'box_B', price: 200, opened: false },
          { open: 'box_C', price: 500, opened: false }
        ]
      };

function getOpenedBoxes(data) {
  return data.boxes.map((open, price, opened) => { 
    console.log({ open, price, opened });
    return { open, price, opened };
  }).filter(boxes => boxes.opened === false);
}

getOpenedBoxes(data);
```

If you study the above, you will realize that your `map`'s callback function, namely:

```
(open, price, opened) => {
    return { open, price, opened }
}
```

misrepresents the map's callback functions. The first parameter is the actual item, the second is the index of the item, while the third is the whole set.

So, instead of the `open` field, you had the current object in the loop. Instead of the `price` field you had the index of the item in the loop. And finally, instead of the `opened` field, you had the whole `boxes`.

Read more about the `map` function here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Particularly this part:

[image]

```js
data = {
        counter: 0,
        boxes: [
          { open: 'box_A', price: 50, opened: true },
          { open: 'box_B', price: 200, opened: false },
          { open: 'box_C', price: 500, opened: false }
        ]
      };

console.log("True elements:");
console.log(data.boxes.filter(item => item.opened)); //If we want to find true elements
console.log("----------------------------------------");
console.log("False elements:");
console.log(data.boxes.filter(item => !item.opened)); //If we want to find false elements
```